# Apply function to frame of characters in R

Tags: r, frame, apply

I've got a set of variables that are characters that I am trying to convert into a binary by creating the following function and using the `apply()` function:

```
a <- as.factor(c("n/a", "False", "False", "True"))
b <- as.factor(c("n/a", "True", "False", "True"))
y <- data.frame(a,b)


conv <- function(x){
    levels(x)[which(levels(x)=="n/a")] <- NA
    levels(x)[which(levels(x)=="False")] <- 0
    levels(x)[which(levels(x)=="True")] <- 1
    x <- as.numeric(levels(x))[x]
    return(x)
}

apply(y,2, conv)
```

However, when I do this, it outputs NAs. Alternatively, if you apply the function by column, it works:

```
conv(y[,1])
conv(y[,2])
```

The expected output should be:

```
y:
NA NA
0 1
0 0 
1 1
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: @akrun I just added it to the post.

Comment: Your function is fine, use a `lapply` instead of `apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is fine you just need to use `lapply`.

```
conv <- function(x){
    levels(x)[which(levels(x)=="n/a")] <- NA
    levels(x)[which(levels(x)=="False")] <- 0
    levels(x)[which(levels(x)=="True")] <- 1
    x <- as.numeric(levels(x))[x]
    return(x)
}

lapply(y,conv)
```

Also if the order of levels is same for all the variables then you could just do this.

```
conv <- function(x){
    levels(x)=c(0,NA,1)
    return(x)
}

lapply(y, conv)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `R`, logical values are TRUE/FALSE and not strings "True", "False".  In addition, `NA` is the missing value

```
y[] <- NA^(is.na(replace(as.matrix(y), y=="n/a", NA)))*+(y=='True')
y
#   a  b
#1 NA NA
#2  0  1
#3  0  0
#4  1  1
```

Comment: How would you preserve the n/a as an `NA`? With this code they are converted into 0

Comment: @coding_heart If you look at the first row, it is NA.

Comment: @coding_heart If you want to update the original dataset, assign it i..e. `y[] <- NA^(is.na(replace(as.matrix(y), y=="n/a", NA)))*+(y=='True')`

Answer (score 1):

A simple `ifelse` can take care of the `NA` requirement. `grepl` can then be used to convert to 0/1, i.e.

```
y[] <- lapply(y[], function(i) ifelse(i == 'n/a', NA, grepl('True', i)*1))
y
#   a  b
#1 NA NA
#2  0  1
#3  0  0
#4  1  1
```